# Find URL and extract its ending

Tags: regex, zapier

I have an string containing multiple words, breaks etc. // The String containts at least two URL, where I need to get the first one and extract the ending.

String:

```
Topic: Scall

Some text. Some words. Some some....

Link1: https://test.com/cancel/AA7ES34QSAGF563N
Link2: https://test.com/move/AA7ES34QSAGF563N
```

I have to find Link1 -> `https://test.com/cancel/AA7ES34QSAGF563N` and then I need the last part -> `AA7ES34QSAGF563N`

The string changes often. So I need to find a solution which exactly finds a link starting with `https://test.com/cancel/` (I got it working to find THE first link, but if another link is placed in the string, this would'nt work anymore). There is also a chance that the last link is another link which I don't need. So searching only for the last link isn't an option.

I am using zapier, and I have only the option to find the value with one line of regex:

[image]

Could someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have your link in a string variable, you can use the built-in function [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) along [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) to get what you want.

```py
>>> link = "https://test.com/cancel/AA7ES34QSAGF563N"
>>> id = link.split("/")[-1]
AA7ES34QSAGF563N
```

Using regex, you could achieve the same result with `[^\/]+$` (working example: https://regex101.com/r/vVWtD0/1)

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention that I used zapier and I can only add one line of regex to find the value

Comment: I updated my answer to add the regex option

Comment: `[^\/]+$` is working great! But it could be that the last link at the end of the string is a different one, then this would no longer work properly.

Comment: Not sure what you suggest, but if you mean that the last part of the URL will change, then the regex will still work

Comment: For example if the string is `https://test.com/cancel/AA7ES34QSAGF563N
https://test.com/move/AA7ES34QSAGF563N
https://google.com/rep/givereputation` It will find "givereputation". But I need "AA7ES34QSAGF563N"

Comment: I would suggest editing your question to include this example as it wasn't really clear you'll have to deal with this specific string